# Entity Framework: long running operation with an open DataReader - is it less robust than immediately fetching all the data?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

Today I have faced the "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command" exception that occurs when you have an open/active data retrieval command and you try to execute another command and this has raised a question in my mind on how less robust might be slowly fetching entities through a IQueryable collection in a long running operation that might span for example 30 minutes or an hour versus pulling immediately all the data via a ToArray() and then using for as long as needed the data now local to the client. Is slowly pulling entities via a IQueryable collection increasing the risk of failures (due to for example loss of connection) versus pulling immediately all the data on the client? Are the two options any different if the entities being retrieved are attached and might require to be persisted to the database? Any difference on how stressful the two alternatives might be for the database server (sql server)?

Comment: What you doing with such amount of data?  ETL jobs?

Comment: It's not the amount of data being fetch from the database that makes it such a long running operation, data from the DB is used to make api calls, that is where time is really being consumed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you fetch the rows slowly, the query plan is still running on SQL Server and may be holding on to memory grants and locks.

And the slow fetching increases the likelihood of a connection failure, especially if the client and SQL Server are not on the same local network.

Comment: What about the fact that entities are attached, does that impact resources server-side? Does it required an active connection to be maintained or does EF eventually close a connection and yet allow persisting updates to those entities at any later time establishing a new connection if required?

Comment: Normally EF will close the connection after querying entities, but the connections are typically pooled on the client, so they're not really closed.  But the SQL Client will seamlessly open a new connection if an idle pooled connection turns out to be broken.